# Increase margin in section titles with titlesec

Tags: titlesec, section-titles

I use the titlesec package to define section titles and use the format

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\raggedright\LARGE}{\thesection}{1ex}{}
```

The font is quite large, so I would prefer to have a wider margin on the right so that I don't get

**This is a long section title**

but rather

**This is a long**

**section title**

How can I achieve that for all section titles?
My question may be similar to this, but parbox seem to be intended for a centered box and it also does not provide a general formatting: [Set margins / make box for the section title with titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472501/set-margins-make-box-for-the-section-title-with-titlesec)

Comment: You can use a `\\\` inside the section title.

Comment: But I'd have to in every section title manually and choose the location of the linebreak? Couldn't I let it automatically break the line if the title would be longer than xx cm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument of `\titleformat` can contain code whose last macro takes the section title as argument. You can exploit this e.g. to put everything in a `\parbox` of given width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
   {\raggedright\LARGE}%
   {\thesection}% 
   {1ex}% vertical space after label
   {\sectionformat}% before code
   [\vspace{1ex}]% after code (add some mor vertical space)
\newcommand*{\sectionformat}[1]{\parbox{5cm}{\raggedright#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a long section title}
Bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Is the first raggedright (before \LARGE) obsolete in this case?

Comment: @johnny7 Oh, yes, I believe so. It would make a difference if you defined the label in a strange way, but in this case it makes no difference.

Comment: I tried the same procedure for subsections, for which I don't use the display option: `\titleformat{\subsection} {\Large}{\thesubsection}{1ex}{\subsectionformat} [\vspace{1cm}] \newcommand*{\subsectionformat}[1]{\parbox{12cm}{\raggedright#1}}` But this doesn't work as expected because the subsection number is not aligned with the first line of the title, it is centered between the two lines. Any ideas?

Comment: @johnny7 Use `\parbox[t]{12cm}{...}`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I really appreciate it!