# Narrowing ToC with titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Following up this question of mine ([Increase margin in section titles with titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606244/increase-margin-in-section-titles-with-titlesec)), I'd like to configure my Table of Contents in a similar way, mainly to substitute the bold font for section titles with a slightly larger font and to remove the dotted lines. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
[0pt]
{}
{\Large\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\hfill\contentspage}                 
[]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This is another long long long long long long section name}
\end{document}
```

The goal is to get in the ToC:

```
1. This is another long long long long
long long section name
```

instead of:

```
1. This is another long long long long long long sec-
tion name
```

So no hyphenation and a specified length. This is to prevent something like this in my document. The package documentation is not very clear to me. The command `\contentsmargin{2.5cm}` does indeed manipulate the right margin in the way I need it but it leads to some misplaced page numbers too.

[image]

Comment: Please post a small complete code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I use LyX and it is hard to reproduce. One section title is just long enough to reach the right margin without a line break so that the page number follows it on the next line but on the left hand side. I also copied the code above from another answer and don't really understand the syntax of titletoc. As said, I want to substitute the bold font of section titles with a larger font and to remove the dotted lines.

Comment: Can't make with Lyx a small fake document and post the resulting code?

Comment: I edited my question with a MWE. Some general remarks about the differences between dottedcontents, titlecontents and contentsmargin would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Answer updated after your edit. No hyphenation and adjustable title width.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** no hyphenation plus a narrow section title by adjusting its left and right "margins".

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}   

\titlecontents{section}%
[0mm]% 
{\Large\raggedright}% no hyphenation
{\contentspush{\makebox[75mm][l]{\thecontentslabel.} \hspace{-45mm}}}% use the makebox width and the \hspace to set the title
{}%
{\contentsmargin{25mm}\hfill\contentspage}%
[\vspace{3ex}]

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
        practical reason is a representation of the things
        in themselves.}
    \section{IntroductionIntroduction IntroductionIntroductionI}
\end{document}
```

[image: f]

Try this code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{section}% <section-type>
[2.3em]%  align left
{\Large}% <above-code> Larger font <<<<<<<<<<<
{\hspace*{-1.5em}\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thecontentslabel.}}% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\hfill\contentspage}% <filler+ page-format>
[\vspace{2ex}]  

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
        practical reason is a representation of the things
        in themselves.}
    \section{IntroductionIntroduction IntroductionIntroductionI}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, one page number is still on the left side. I added a graphic above. What does the 1.5em indicate in your code?

Comment: @johnny7 Which number?

Comment: @johnny7 [1.5em] is the indent used in `book` . Change the value and see what happens.

Comment: With a specific length of a chapter name, the page number still appears left as in the image I added in my question, no matter whether I use the makebox.

Comment: @johnny7 Are you able to compile my code, as it is?

Comment: When pasting your code with the new section name in Overleaf, the page number still appears on the left.

Comment: @johnny7 Your question was about having line breaks in section titles in the TOC. For a very specific title or word, if TeX hyphenation fails to find a nice place, you can have strange behaviors. You need to help TeX suggesting an hyphen point.

Comment: I didn't realize at first it can make perfect line breaks because the chapter name fitted on one line, but just the page number not anymore. I don't want hyphenation but I would be fine with the last word in a second line. I can add a short title with a line break but then the section name in the header has that too. The problem with the makebox is that it doesn't include the page number, right?

Comment: @johnny7 The makebox is only for the section number, not the title or the page.

Comment: I see. How can I put the section title in a parbox with a specific length and \raggedright, so that no hyphenation is made? It worked perfectly for the section titles in the document body (see my linked question). Let's say I wanted to break section titles in the ToC at the middle of the page.

Comment: @johnny7 Please ask another question with a MWE if you want a narrowed TOC.

Comment: I edited this question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again! Unfortunately, it is still a mess in my document. The page numbers don't align with the right margin. I played around with the numbers a lot but didn't manage to get them to their default position right-aligned.